# Is there a soft Goldstino theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, fermions, symmetry-breaking

For ordinary spontaneously broken symmetries, you can demonstrate relations between S-matrix elements with a soft [goldstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson) emission and another S-matrix element without the emission.

If I break SUSY I get [Nambu-Goldstone fermions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson#Nambu.E2.80.93Goldstone_fermions). Does there exist a relation between matrix elements with a soft goldstino emission and a matrix element without the emission? Basically, what is the complication because the soft particle is a fermion? References are also useful.

Answer (score 3):

Soft goldstino theorems? Sure, [Goldstino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstino) has some illustrative references, like [Uematsu & Zachos](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213%2882%2990431-X), [available here](https://www.academia.edu/6176941/Structure_of_phenomenological_lagrangians_for_broken_supersymmetry), which has the Adler zeroes exhibited explicitly, without exciting deviations from the boson/pion case. Basically the underlying principles are the same, and goldstinos decouple at vanishing momenta.